# Change architecture of Ruby app to be more object oriented, readable

Tags: ruby, aws-lambda, slack-api, jira-rest-api

I'm working on a Slack bot for service desk which sends direct message to user on a Slack when their ticket will be on `user_action_needed` status. I'm using AWS Lambda to handle Jira incoming webhooks. Everything works well but I think I've got an issue with whole architecture of the app - I quess the code is not so readable, name of the class probably doesn't match what they do.

First of all I've got the `handler` on AWS lambda:

```
  module JiraHandler
    extend self
    def handle(event:, _context:)
      Parsers::JiraParser.new(event).call
      { statusCode: 200 }
    end
  end
```

`Parsers::JiraParser` is responsible not only for parsing events but it calls another class which grabs `userId` from Slack, and then inside of `GetUserId` I've got another class which sends message to user. So at the end if you call `Parsers::JiraParser` class you will receive slack message instead of parsed data.

Details of what I wrote about each class below:

`Parsers::JiraParser`

```
module Parsers
  class JiraParser
    def initialize(event)
      payload = event['body']
      @event = JSON.parse(payload)
    end

    def call
      ::Slack::GetUserId.new(reporter_email, reporter_name, ticket_number).call
    end
    # reporter_email, reporter_name, ticket_number are methods to pull data by .dig from event hash
```

`GetUserId`

```
  class GetUserId
    SLACK_LOOKUP_BY_EMAIL = 'https://slack.com/api/users.lookupByEmail'

    def initialize(email, name, ticket_number)
      @email = email
      @name = name
      @ticket_number = ticket_number
    end

    def call
      user_id = set_slack_user.dig('user', 'id')
      ::Slack::SlackMessenger.new(user_id, name, ticket_number).call
    end

    def set_slack_user
      HTTParty.get(SLACK_LOOKUP_BY_EMAIL, options)
    end
```

`SlackMessanger`

```
module Slack
  class SlackMessenger
    SLACK_API_ENDPOINT = 'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage'

    def initialize(user_id, name, ticket_number)
      @user_id = user_id
      @name = name
      @ticket_number = ticket_number
    end

    def call
      HTTParty.post(SLACK_API_ENDPOINT, body: params, headers: headers)
    end
```

I don't think this is a good approach, should I create an extra class where all those classes will be called? or maybe I should use monads?

Comment: Hello! Your question is well presented. You might get more feedback on codereview.stackexchange.com/, because your code seems to be already working.